# python stacktrace at firefoxdriver.prototype.findelement internal

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I'm using `selenium` with `firefox` to load a webpage. The page uses `ajax` to load new content on clicking the **Display More Results** button.

However when I try to find this button and simulate a click, it gives the following `Stacktrace` error. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

**Here's my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://dir.indiamart.com/search.mp?ss=plastic+machinery")


try:
    elem = elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(lambda driver : driver.find_element_by_id('scroll2'))
    elem.click()
    print "clicked"
except Exception as e:
    print e


driver.close()
```

**Here's the error I'm getting:**

```
Message: 
Stacktrace:
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpAQcOR7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10770)
    at FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement (file:///tmp/tmpAQcOR7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js:10779)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h (file:///tmp/tmpAQcOR7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12661)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_ (file:///tmp/tmpAQcOR7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12666)
    at DelayedCommand.prototype.execute/< (file:///tmp/tmpAQcOR7/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js:12608)
```

Comment: The error seems to be coming from the firefox driver itself. The firefox driver is a firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is because there is no error message. However, this syntax looks rather strange:

```
elem = elem = WebDriverWait(...
```

Also, I noticed that when I went to that page the div with the id "scroll2" was not visible.  The visible one was "scroll4".  You'll probably have to write some other code to look for the visible div with "scroll" in it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Accidentally typed that twice. And I do find "scroll2" when I visit the website. It's the very first **Display More Results** button. 
I got around the problem by executing the script that was being called on the button click a couple of times, rather than waiting for the element to appear.